# Redis - ZRANGEBYSCORE with key matching a regex

Tags: redis

I'm trying to get the value of the best key in a sorted set. 
This is my query at the moment:

```
ZREVRANGEBYSCORE genre1 +inf -inf WITHSCORES LIMIT 0 1
```

This is an example of an add in my set:

```
ZADD "genre1|genre2|genre3" 3.25153 "film"
```

I'd like to use the query in a way like this

```
ZREVRANGEBYSCORE *genre1* +inf -inf WITHSCORES LIMIT 0 1
```

to match keys containing "...|genre1|..." and not only keys like "genre1".
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished in two or three steps:

1) Use [`SCAN`](https://redis.io/commands/scan) or `KEYS` to find the [`keys`](https://redis.io/commands/keys) matching your pattern.

```
SCAN 0 MATCH "*genre1*"
1) "9"
2) 1) "genre1|genre2|genre3"
   2) "genre1|genre4"
```

2) For each key, use [`TYPE`](https://redis.io/commands/type) to test if it is a Sorted Set. This is only important if you may have other *genre1* keys on the db

```
TYPE "genre1|genre4"
zset
```

3) Run your `ZREVRANGEBYSCORE <key> +inf -inf WITHSCORES LIMIT 0 1` for each key.

See [this answer on how you can SCAN for a given type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462457/how-can-i-get-all-of-the-sets-in-redis/59564727#59564727). You can modify the Lua script to include the `ZREVRANGEBYSCORE` and get your results atomically on a single call.

Finally, consider reviewing if storing the genre combinations is optimal in your case. You may use a sorted set per genre, and then use [`ZUNIONSTORE`](https://redis.io/commands/zunionstore) or [`ZINTERSTORE`](https://redis.io/commands/zinterstore) to get scored combinations.