# How to get all hashmap match with prefix in Redis?

Tags: redis, node-redis, redis-cluster

I have redis data with the format below:

```
HMSET name:1 key "value"
HMSET name:2 key "value2"
HMSET name:3 key "value3"
HMSET name:a key "valuea"
```

How to get all hashmap with prefix is "name:" the same result below:

```
name:1 key "value"
name:2 key "value2"
name:3 key "value3"
```

Comment: Did you check Redis SCAN https://redis.io/commands/scan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [`SCAN`](https://redis.io/commands/scan) and not `KEYS`, as `KEYS` may block your server for too long.

You want to filter by hashmap type. See more in [How can I get all of the sets in redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462457/how-can-i-get-all-of-the-sets-in-redis/59564727#59564727)

Then, you want to append the field-values to the response. For that you need [Lua Scripting](https://redis.io/commands/eval).

This script should get you started:

```
local result = redis.call('SCAN', ARGV[1], 'MATCH', ARGV[2])
local filtered = {}
for _,key in ipairs(result[2]) do
    if redis.call('TYPE', key).ok == ARGV[3] then
        local keyWithHash = {}
        keyWithHash[1] = key
        keyWithHash[2] = redis.call('HGETALL', key)
        table.insert(filtered, keyWithHash)
    end
end
result[2] = filtered
return result
```

If you are using Redis 6 you can optimize it by making the `SCAN` use the `TYPE` option instead of filtering one by one by calling [`TYPE` command](https://redis.io/commands/type).

Use as:

```
EVAL "local result = redis.call('SCAN', ARGV[1], 'MATCH', ARGV[2]) local filtered = {} for _,key in ipairs(result[2]) do     if redis.call('TYPE', key).ok == ARGV[3] then      local keyWithHash = {}      keyWithHash[1] = key        keyWithHash[2] = redis.call('HGETALL', key)         table.insert(filtered, keyWithHash)     end end result[2] = filtered return result" 0 0 "name:*" hash
```

Pre-test:

```
HMSET name:1 key "value"
HMSET name:2 key "value2"
HMSET name:3 key "value3"
HMSET name:a key "valuea"
SET name:notAhash "asdasd"
```

Test:

```
> EVAL "local result ... return result" 0 0 "name:*" hash
1) "0"
2) 1) 1) "name:a"
      2) 1) "key"
         2) "valuea"
   2) 1) "name:3"
      2) 1) "key"
         2) "value3"
   3) 1) "name:2"
      2) 1) "key"
         2) "value2"
   4) 1) "name:1"
      2) 1) "key"
         2) "value"
```